# remove all blank space before double and after double quote marks

Tags: javascript, regex

I've used below formula to remove all blank space before " and after " but not effort.

```js
var test_string = '{" 1 ": "b.) some pasta salad", "   10": "   a.) Yes, some bread", "11  ": "   a.) eggs and toast  " }'
var test_string_format = test_string.replace(/^[ '"]+|[ '"]+$|( ){2,}/g,'$1')
    
console.log(test_string_format)
```

How can I use regex to get the desired output?

`{"1":"b.) some pasta salad","10":"a.) Yes, some bread","11":"a.) eggs and toast" }`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const regex = /(\s*["]\s*)/gm;

var test_string =  = `{" 1 ": "b.) some pasta salad", "   10": "   a.) Yes, some bread", "11  ": "   a.) eggs and toast  " }
`;

console.log(test_string.replace(regex, '"'))
```

Comment: It works but, you don't need: 1) the capture group, 2) the character class around `"`, 3) the `m` modifier.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte You are right, the m modifier canbe removed. About grouping and the character class, I just wanted to make it more readable, but `/\s*"\s*/g` works too.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the string content is always valid JSON, you can do it like this:

```js
var str = '{" 1 ": "b.) some pasta salad", "   10": "   a.) Yes, some bread", "11  ": "   a.) eggs and toast  " }'

const res=JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(JSON.parse(str)).map(e=>e.map(e=>e.trim()))))

console.log(res)
```

I know, this is kind of a "goofy" solution, but it works for the given sample string.

The snippet parses the JSON string, then converts the resulting object into an array of arrays. Each element of each sub-array is then `.trim()`-med and at the end of the operation the object is reconstructed via `.Object.fromEntries()` and turned back into a JSON string via `JSON.stringify()`.

Answer (score 2):

Replace zero or more spaces, followed by a quote, followed by zero or more spaces, with just the quote:

```js
replaceAll(/ *" */g, '"')
```

```js
const test_string = '{" 1 ": "b.) some pasta salad", "   10": "   a.) Yes, some bread", "11  ": "   a.) eggs and toast  " }'

const trimmed = test_string.replaceAll(/ *" */g, '"');

console.log(trimmed);
```

Comment: `replaceAll` will not work on all environments. Instead, use `replace`

Answer (score 2):

```js
const test_string = '{" 1 ": "b.) some pasta salad", "   10": "   a.) Yes, some bread", "11  ": "   a.) eggs and toast  " }';

const test_string_format = test_string.replace(/\s*"\s*/g, '"');

console.log(test_string_format);
```

- `\s`: matches any white-space character
- `*`: matches zero or more of the prev character(`\s`)
- `"`: matches the double quote character

Answer (score 0):

```js
    console.log('{" 1 ": "b.) some pasta salad", "   10": "   a.) Yes, some bread", "11  ": "   a.) eggs and toast  " }'
    .replaceAll(/( *\" +)|( +\ *)/ig,'"'))
```

Comment: `replaceAll` will not work on all environments. Instead, use `replace`